# Connecting a Samsung Tablet with my Windows PC (mainly for accessing and modifying hand-written files)

Tags: windows, android

I'm a math student, and I have found it convenient to write everything on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 6 Lite). But it is much more pleasant for me to read my notes (I use Samsung notes) on my windows pc. The current method I use is just sending everything via email, but as the hand-written files are very large (~6MB each), it is making my email full. I also often modify my notes (on the tablet) as I'm reading through them, but this is problematic because I will have to resend the file to my email again to see the updated version. Is there a way to access the files from my tablet directly from my laptop? Gdrive is not a good option unfortunately, I have a lot of large files and my capacity on drive is already low.

**Edit:** Should be usable over Wi-Fi, and doesn't use cloud storage. I am also willing to consider one time payment for the product if it is below 10eur.

Comment: You should add more details about the preferred solution (uses USB cable, Wifi, mobile data). Cloud storage should (not) be used and so on.

Comment: Why  cloud storage is not an option?